# PyInstaller does not run properly when Python project is debugged in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyinstaller

I have a Python project setup in Visual Studio 17.
I debug the project. Stop the debug session. Fix the code.
Run a batch file, outside of Studio, executing PyInstaller to build the .exe
PyInstaller will either report an error or hang.
If I don't use Visual Studio, there are no issues running PyInstaller.

Any suggestions on where to look for the problem?

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio is still hanging onto some files, and is locking them; closing it removes these locks, but if you could figure out what is potentially locking some files in the first place, you might be able to prevent it.